# Side by side horizontal legends in in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to get my ggplot legends to appear side by side, underneath the plot with the variable names above the symbols, as they are in [this](https://kohske.wordpress.com/2010/12/25/various-position-adjustments-of-legend-in-ggplot2/) blog post (the second plot). The `opts` function is now defunct, and `theme` does not appear to replicate its behaviour...

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y=price, shape = cut, group=interaction(cut, color), color=color)) +
geom_point() +
#opts(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.position = "bottom")
#potential options, not all seem have an effect...
theme(legend.direction = "horizontal") +
theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
theme(legend.box = "vertical") +
theme(legend.title.align = 0)
```

[image]

...using my MS paint skills to illustrate the desired plot.

Comment: You need to have `theme(legend.box = "horizontal")` instead of `"vertical"`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Adapting from the previous suggestions with `legend.box = "horizontal"`, I have found that you can get the legend titles on top using `title.position = "top"` in the guides for the `scale_` functions. These have to be defined for each variable that makes up the legend else the title will be to the left.

```
ggplot(data = diamonds, 
       mapping = aes(x = carat, y = price, shape = cut,
                     group=interaction(cut, color), color=color)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.box = "horizontal",
        legend.position="bottom") +
  scale_shape(guide = guide_legend(title.position = "top")) +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide = guide_legend(title.position = "top", nrow = 1))
```

[image]

You could shift the titles to the center, as I suggested in the question,  using `title.hjust = 0.5`. However, upon inspection, doing so might confuse the reader as to which colours/points refers to which variable.

Answer (score 33):

You need to specify `theme(legend.box = "horizontal")`

Try this:

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y=price, shape = cut, group=interaction(cut, color), color=color)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", 
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.box = "horizontal"
        )
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to get the cut and color titles above the symbols?

Comment: legend.direction=vertical, Error in theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20, hjust = 1, vjust = 1,  : 
  object 'vertical' not found

Comment: @MonaJalal Try with vertical in quotes: `"vertical"`

Comment: Perfect, the theme(legend.box = "horizontal") was key for me in a separate plot

Answer (score 5):

@gjbel - I think to make the legend title above the symbols you either need to change legend direction from horizontal to vertical or remove legend direction entirely as the default is vertical:

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y=price, shape = cut, group=interaction(cut, color), color=color)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.direction = "vertical", 
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.box = "horizontal"
        )
```

OR

```
library("ggplot2")
    ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y=price, shape = cut, group=interaction(cut, color), color=color)) +
      geom_point() +
      theme(legend.position = "bottom",
            legend.box = "horizontal"
            )
```