# ggplot - Controlling each component of the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, legend

I create a simple plot with size and color:

```
my.df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4), y=c(1,2,3,4), grp=c("a", "a", "b", "b"), 
wt=c(1,2,3,4))
p1 <- ggplot(my.df, aes(x, y, col=grp, size=wt)) + geom_point()
p1 <- p1 + scale_colour_manual(values=c("red", "blue"), name="Group")
p1 <- p1 + scale_size(name="Size")
p1 <- p1 + theme(legend.position = c(0.85, 0.35))
p1
```

By default, the legend for size and color are put on top of each other
(I can easily choose which of the two goes on top).

I'd like them side-by-side within my plot.
(Or anywhere I'd like to put them separately, for that matter.)

There is no "position" in guide_legend(), which would be a convenient way to handle this.  And theme(legend.position) can only be used to define a single position.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Side by side horizontal legends in in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065604/side-by-side-horizontal-legends-in-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 0):

You could define `legend.box = "horizontal"` besides specifying the position `legend.position`.

```
p1 <- ggplot(my.df, aes(x, y, col=grp, size=wt)) + geom_point()  + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("red", "blue"), name="Group") + 
  scale_size(name="Size")

p1 + theme(legend.box = "horizontal", legend.position = c(0.85, 0.35))
```